# Jquery regex search substring or wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search

I have this regex search:
I am searching for product price in an array.
The search matches product number (in this case: "04.1177")

Depending wheter a product is a "range of products" or a single product
Productnumbers has between 7 and 12 characters.
"04.1177" is a single product, while "04.1177.0000" defines a range of products.
I want to find all occurrences of the first 7 characters, disregarding the last 5.

```
sentInfo = "04.1177"

function getPrices(sentInfo) { 
var searchFor = sentInfo.toString()

 // Make sure we use . instead of , in string
 var search_term = (sentInfo).replace(/\,/g,'.');                               

var search = new RegExp(search_term, "i");
    if (sdsInfo) {      
        sdsFilter = $.grep(sdsInfo.priser, function (element, index) {
            var sted = search.test("^"+element.FIELD1+"\//")
            return sted;
        }); 
    }
$.each( sdsFilter, function ( index, value ) {
    $('.'+kat).html((value.FIELD2).toFixed(2));
    $('.'+kat).data('price',value.FIELD2);
});
}
```

The above script works in itself.

The array looks something like this:

```
{"FIELD1":"01.1407","FIELD2":259, "FIELD3":"name"},{"FIELD1":"04.1177.0000","FIELD2":349, "FIELD3":"name"},{"FIELD1":"04.1177.0100","FIELD2":349, "FIELD3":"name"}
```

Using the above script I get match IF the value.FIELD1 matches the entire string. BUT it omits results (returning null or false) if the string is longer

Search: 04.1177 in 04.1177 = true
Search: 04.1177 in 04.1177.0000 = false

I need to make sure both of the above is true.
Any ideas ?

Sorry if this queston is somehow duplicated, but I cannot find a solution anywhere...

Comment: Thanks to indent code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for certain you want to examine the first 7 characters of `var` and ignore the rest, just run your regex against `var.substring(0,7)` instead of the full `var`.  (This returns seven characters, starting at index zero -- therefore the first seven characters of the string.)

And if you know that you're only looking for exact matches of those 7 characters, just test equality instead of using a regex.

There are some undefined variables in your code (it looks like you may have translated some variable names but not others) --  `kat`, `sdsInfo` (is that the array?), `sdsInfo.priser` -- so I'm not 100% certain the below code matches your intent, but it should be enough to demonstrate the idea:

```js
var arr = [{
  "FIELD1": "01.1407",
  "FIELD2": 259,
  "FIELD3": "name"
}, {
  "FIELD1": "04.1177.0000",
  "FIELD2": 349,
  "FIELD3": "name"
}, {
  "FIELD1": "04.1177.0100",
  "FIELD2": 349,
  "FIELD3": "name"
}]

function getPrices(sentInfo) {
  // Make sure we use . instead of , in string
  var search_term = sentInfo.toString().replace(/\,/g, '.');

  arr.forEach(function(value) {
    // compare the first 7 chars of FIELD1 to search_term, which is already 7 chars:
    if (value.FIELD1.substring(0,7) === search_term) {
      console.log("matched: ", value)
      //$('.' + kat).data('price', value.FIELD2);
    }
  });

}

getPrices("04.1177")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why adding the substring to the search-field fixed it. but I am very grateful for you pointing that out.

Comment: No trouble!  Added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Thank you again. as to the undefined variables - it's part of the larger script I run. I just copied out the search script I was using and forgot to  remove them